# validation of records in fluentd

Tags: validation, fluentd

How do we implement validation in fluent config that's built using ruby?
I tried the following:

```
    <filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    is_integer ${record['ip_src'].to_i.to_s =~ /^[0-9]+$/ ? 'true' : 'false'}
    is_not_null ${record['ip_src'].nil? ? 'false' : 'true'}
  </record>
</filter>
```

If it's null, i dont want this to be sent to kafka.
Note: I'm sending to kafka with the following :

```
    <match test>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type kafka2
    @id kafka2_matched
    brokers kafka01:9092
    use_event_time true
    get_kafka_client_log true
    topic_key event
    default_topic event

    <filter is_integer true>
      @type record_transformer
      enable_ruby true
      <record>
        keep true
      </record>
    </filter>
    <filter is_not_null true>
      @type record_transformer
      enable_ruby true
      <record>
        keep true
      </record>
    </filter>
  </store>

  <store>
    @type null
    @id null_output
  </store>
</match>
```

It doesn't seem to be working for me